# Instantiate class from a collection of subclasses, while maintaining access to static members in Typescript

Tags: typescript, types, abstract-class, abstract, typescript-types

I think I may have stumbled into a situation where what I want is best described by having both `static` and `abstract` on a member of an abstract class, but that doesn't seem to be possible in typescript.

The closest I can get is the below:

```
abstract class A {

    s: string;
    n: number;
    static identifier: string;

    constructor(s: string, n: number) {
        this.s = s;
        this.n = n;
    }

}

class B extends A {

    static identifier: string = "B";

}

class C extends A {

    static identifier: string = "C";

}

function identifyAndInstantiate(identifier: string, classes: (typeof A)[]) {

    var identifiedClass = classes.find((classCandidateConstructor: typeof A) => { return identifier == classCandidateConstructor.identifier });
    if (!identifiedClass) return;
    
    //error here: Cannot create an instance of an abstract class.(2511)
    var instance = new identifiedClass("foo", 12);

}

var classes: (typeof A)[] = [
    B,
    C
]
```

I've tried a variety of different approaches to the collection type. The closest I could get working was a Map from the static member type to instances of the class, but then you have to individually map the values to their classes.

Another thing I tried was to use a `Newable<T>` type that describes its constructor, but this removes the ability to refer to the subclass' static properties (as does seemingly anything else that makes the constructor available).

Is there a way to both refer to a subclass' static properties and its constructor when having retrieved it from a collection of classes?

Comment: Can you make the code a [mre] with a little structure instead of `...` so we have something common to test against?

Comment: [This approach](https://tsplay.dev/WPOQem) is how I'd proceed but without a [mre] of can't be sure. Please do [edit] to provide a testable example.

Comment: @jcalz I've now added a minimal reproducible example, as per your very sensible advice.

From what I can tell, the approach you suggest is a very good solution, though Etienne Laurin provides what I'd consider to be the perfect answer to my question below (I appreciate you may have provided that answer exactly, or perhaps a better one, provided I did a better job of asking the question).

Thanks, though, I never thought of putting the constructor in an interface! Very inventive!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works almost as-is, with the following changes:

- You can't refer to `subclass.identifier` unless that property is in the type of `subclassesOfA`
- You can't instantiate a `typeof A` but you can instantiate a `{ new(): A }`

```js
function foo(subclassIdentifier: string, subclassesOfA: {
  identifier: string,
  new (): A
}[]): void {
    let subclass = subclassesOfA.find((subclass) =>
        subclass.identifier == subclassIdentifier);
    if (subclass) {
        let instance = new subclass();
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks very much! I've asked other people with more typescript experience than me and this is the only answer I've seen that does what I need, and to boot it's very clear what it's doing (which is demanding precisely what I need and no more from the type of the parameter in the method's type signature).

Answer couldn't have been better.

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation

This can be done by defining an abstract property **in the base abstract class (A)** and implementing it in each concrete subclass (B, C, etc.). This way, each subclass has a unique identifier that can be used to distinguish them when stored in a collection.

### Simple Code Example

```
abstract class A {
  static identifier: string;

  abstract someMethod(): void;
}

class B extends A {
  static identifier = 'B';

  someMethod(): void {
    console.log('Method in B');
  }
}

class C extends A {
  static identifier = 'C';

  someMethod(): void {
    console.log('Method in C');
  }
}

function foo(subclassIdentifier: string, subclassesOfA: (typeof A)[]): void {
  let subclass = subclassesOfA.find(subclass => subclass.identifier === subclassIdentifier);

  if (subclass) {
    let instance = new subclass();
    instance.someMethod();
  } else {
    console.error('Subclass not found');
  }
}

// Example usage
foo('B', [B, C]); // Output: Method in B
foo('C', [B, C]); // Output: Method in C
```

### Breakdown

- Each concrete subclass (B, C, etc.) defines a static identifier property.
- The abstract base class (A) declares a static property identifier that needs to be implemented by each subclass.
- The foo function takes an identifier and a collection of subclass constructors and creates an instance of the matching subclass.

You can now refer to both the static properties and constructors of the subclasses while having a common abstract property for identification.

Comment: How does this solve the "*Cannot create an instance of an abstract class*" error which the OP was getting?

Comment: @Bergi you're exactly right, if I copy the above into typescript playground I find myself unable to instantiate `subclass`.

While this was a well written answer, it didn't address the crux of the matter (may well be my fault for not communicating the problem as well as I'd have liked.)

Comment: apologies, looks like I misunderstood the question a bit